# How to Test Property for Data Type Equality

Tags: c#

I am trying to determine the type of a property and assign it a value from an `SqlDataReader`.  Below is my code and the three variations I have seen on here but none of which work. (`dr` is the DataReader, `response.FundsParms` is a data class, fields in the DataReader have the same names as the data class)

```
foreach (
    PropertyDescriptor prop in
        TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(response.FundsParms)
            .Cast<PropertyDescriptor>()
            .Where(prop => HasColumn(dr, prop.Name)))
{
    if (prop.GetType() == string)  //Error here is Expression Expected
    {
        prop.SetValue(response.FundsParms, dr[prop.Name].ToString());
    }
    if (prop.GetType() == typeof(decimal))  //Pre compile message - Operator is can be used
    {
        prop.SetValue(response.FundsParms, Convert.ToDecimal(dr[prop.Name]));
    }
    if (prop is int)  //Error: The given expression is never of the given type
    {
        prop.SetValue(response.FundsParms, Convert.ToInt32(dr[prop.Name]));
    }
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: you mean 'typeof( string)', I assume you are getting compile errors. You dont say what goes wrong but that code wont compile

Comment: A close vote because it does not appear to be about programming? Hello?

Comment: Isn't `prop.GetType()` always `typeof(PropertyDescriptor)`?

Comment: I didn't issue the vote, but notice that its details are "Question asking for debugging help should indicate [...] what problem is being described." Presumably the voter was unhappy with the lack of description of *what* wasn't working.

Comment: @DanJ Point taken so updated the question.  Incorrect close vote it should have been "unclear what you're asking" IMO if that is the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using [`PropertyType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertydescriptor.propertytype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of [`TypeDescriptor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor(v=vs.110).aspx) which return object of the [`Type`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type(v=vs.110).aspx) of the Property:

```
if ( prop.PropertyType == typeof(int))
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks I knew I was missing something silly.

Answer (score 2):

Notice this:

```
foreach (
        PropertyDescriptor prop in
```

The variable `prop` is of type [`PropertyDescriptor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
if (prop.GetType() == string)
```

[`GetType()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns a `Type` representing the *instance on which it's called*. What is the type of the variable `prop`? It's `typeof(PropertyDescriptor)`.

[`PropertyDescriptor.PropertyType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertydescriptor.propertytype(v=vs.110).aspx) will identify the type of the property that `prop` is actually describing.